# Adding delay to single button on off circuit

Tags: analog, button

I'm using this circuit to turn on and off.
[image]

When I press the button circuit instantly turns on or off. I want the circuit to switch after pressing the button for 2-3 seconds. I tried to change C1 and C2 values but nothing changed.

I would like to know how can I add this delay to the circuit.

Comment: I think if you made C1 and C2 a lot higher in value (maybe 470 uF and 100 uF) you could put (say) a 10 kohm resistor in series with the switch and get some improvement on delay. Also try making R6 more like 1 Mohm and R3 more like 100 kohm. Where did the circuit come from? It might be not worth the effort and redesigning using a monostable.

Comment: @Andyaka yes with these capacitor values circuit is not work. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ghu7kSupXuc this is the source. Do you think this circuit need to be to much effort for button delay.